# Java:Get a value from a thread using some polling mechanism and kill the thread based on the value…?

Tags: java

how can i poll for value from another thread. 
For eg: I have a method in ThreadA which calls a method of another Thread(ThreadB). I need to use some polling mechanism so that for every 5 seconds I should be able to check the value of return type(String) of that method and based on the value (say SUCCESS/FAILURE) i should be able to kill the ThreadB.
How can it be done.. Please help.

This can be done with Observer patter, but now small change -- I am polling every 5 secnds for the value of threadB. but the value of ThreadB will change only after 10 min. here my question is in every 5 seconds how can i get the value of ThreadB without invoking it everytime. ThreadB can only be invoked once.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to register ThreadA as Observer of ThreadB? Everytime the value of ThreadB changes, ThreadA will be notified and can decide, if he should kill ThreadB. For Observer pattern see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Comment: Andreas --This can be done with Observer patter, but now small change -- I am polling every 5 secnds for the value of threadB. but the value of ThreadB will change only after 10 min. here my question is in every 5 seconds how can i get the value of ThreadB without invoking it everytime. ThreadB can only be invoked once.

Comment: I don't see the change. Only ThreadB knows, when it changes, so it should be in control to notify ThreadA, when it changes. That's what the observer pattern is for. With polling ThreadA has to guess, when the value in ThreadB could possible change. Even in the case of periodical change possibilities (e.g. every full hour), ThreadA has to poll in the same period (e.g. 5 minutes after every full hour). For polling only once, ThreadA must know, when the state of ThreadB will change to the desired value. But if you know it already, you haven'T to poll ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
public class Blofeld extends Thread {

    private volatile boolean isBombDefused;
    private volatile int count = 10;

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Blofeld starts countdown");
        while (!isBombDefused) {
            System.out.println(count + " seconds and counting...");
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            count--;
            if (count <= 0) {
                System.out.println("This is the price of failure...");
                throw new RuntimeException("BOOOOM!");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Mr. Bond! Mr. Bond! We can do a deal!");
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void cutRedWire() {
        System.out.println("SNIP!");
        isBombDefused = true;
    }
}

public class Bond {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Blofeld blofeld = new Blofeld();
        blofeld.start();
        while (blofeld.getCount() > 007) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Bond works frantically");
        }
        blofeld.cutRedWire();
    }
}
```

EDIT: After comment from artbristol made both fields volatile so that the master values are always read.

Comment: Very amusing example. For thread safety, `isBombDefused` and `count` need to be `volatile` or poor Bond might be blown up despite cutting the wire in time!

Comment: Modifications! Was the example not exciting enough?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to work with low level threads, you could:

- embed thread b's method (mB) in a runnable and submit it to an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and store the `Future` f returned by submit
- catch `InterruptedException` in mB and exit when caught
- embed thread a's method in a runnable and submit it to a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) that runs every 5 seconds
- if your condition is true, call `f.cancel(true)` or `shutdownNow` the first executor

Ps: that's if you really want to poll every 5 seconds, if you prefer a more real time thing, Andreas' comment makes more sense.

Comment: I haven't used ExecuterService till now, but when we use executerService i read somewhere saying that, we should wait till future returns a value.but let me try both the above solutions. Thanks guys :)

Comment: You don't have to wait, but you can by calling f.get(). That also enables you to catch uncaught exceptions.